# Create sql query in sonata admin

Tags: sql, sonata-admin

I use sonata admin in my project. i created two admin classes exam and student. i want to create an action in exam class that shows all students that should pass the exam after creating a new exam, this is the sql query that i want:

```
"Select * from student,exam where student.codeAdministration=exam.codeAdministration"
```

examAdmin.php:

```
<?php

namespace Exam\ExamBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class ExamAdmin extends Admin
{
     ////
     protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
     {
        //////
     }
     protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
     {
        ////
     }
     protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
     {
        /////
     }

     protected function configureShowField(ShowMapper $showMapper)
     {
         //////
     }

}
```

i tried this query without putting the condition of WHERE but it does not work:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $query = $this->modelManager->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT s FROM Exam\ExamBundle\Entity\student s');

    $listMapper

        ->add('student', 'sonata_type_model', array('required' => true, 'query' => $query))
}
```

How can i create this action with this query??

exam.php:

```
<?php

namespace Exam\ExamBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
class Exam
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $idExam

    ////////

    /**
     * @var \Examens\ExamensBundle\Entity\Administration
     */
    private $codeAdministration;

    //////
    public function getIdExam()
    {
        return $this->idExam;
    }

    ///////
    public function setCodeAdministration(\Exam\ExamBundle\Entity\Administration $codeAdministration = null)
    {
        $this->codeAdministration = $codeAdministration;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get codeAdministration
     *
     * @return \Exam\ExamBundle\Entity\Administration 
     */
    public function getCodeAdministration()
    {
        return $this->codeAdministration;
    }
    ///////
}
```

Comment: So whats the question? That we create this for you? You should at least give it a shot yourself because we're not just people doing work for you...

Comment: No, i just forgot to write my code. i edited my post, this is what i try but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to do the query yourself instead of letting sonata do it for you?

Comment: Execuse me but i am new in sonata, Does sonata can do it for me? because i want the query in examAdmin class and i use another entity which is student.

Comment: If you have set-up your entity relations correctly then you should only write **->add('student', 'sonata_type_model'** the rest is done automatically.. If it doesn't work add your entity code to your question please :)

Comment: Look, what i want exactly is when i add a new exam and after clicking on create button, i want to create a button "show student list" with the existing buttons update, update and close, delete. i will try the code above..

Comment: It does not work for me. any help..

Comment: What does it do? Please show me your entity code...

Comment: i edited my post, this is my exam entity. how to create an action like update and delete actions in configureFormFields??

Comment: How does the admin class has supposed to know of a student if there is no field in the entity called **student**?

Comment: Both classes exam and student have a foreign key codeAdministration from another entity which is administration. the relations are correct because it works perfectly in other functions.